# Display data from database with Select Option Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, select-options

first I want to apologize because I just learned Codeigniter, I have problems to display data from the database by using the Select Option, there is no error but the data does not appear, for your information, i have joined 3 tables.

Here's my Controller

```
class Harga extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('m_harga');
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->database();
}

function index(){
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $data['tabel_harga'] = $this->m_harga->tampil_data();
  $this->load->view('v_harga',$data);
}
```

Here's my Model

```
class M_harga extends CI_Model{
 function tampil_data(){
    $this->db->order_by('id_harga','ASC');
    return $this->db->from('tabel_harga')
    ->join('tabel_vendor','tabel_vendor.id_vendor=tabel_harga.id_vendor')
    ->join('tabel_hari','tabel_hari.id_hari=tabel_harga.id_hari')
    ->get()
    ->result();
}
```

and Here's my Views

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">All</option>
      <?php
       foreach($tabel_harga as $u)
       {
        echo '<option value="'.$u['id_vendor'].'">'.$u['nama_vendor'].'</option>';
       }
      ?>
</select>
```

I will be very grateful if you help me, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

The data doesn't appear probably because you're using `result()` which returns `object` and you're getting data as `array` in your `view`.

**Model**

```
class M_harga extends CI_Model{

    function tampil_data(){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tabel_harga'); 
        $this->db->join('tabel_vendor','tabel_vendor.id_vendor=tabel_harga.id_vendor', 'INNER');
        $this->db->join('tabel_hari','tabel_hari.id_hari=tabel_harga.id_hari', 'INNER');
        $this->db->order_by('id_harga','ASC'); 

        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array(); // use result_array() instead of result() as you're getting value as an array in your view.

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to check `$tabel_harga` for values in your `view` ie

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">All</option>
      <?php
          if(!empty($tabel_harga)){
              foreach($tabel_harga as $u){
      ?>            
                  <option value="<?php echo $u['id_vendor']; ?>"><?php echo $u['nama_vendor']; ?></option>
      <?php 
              }
          }
      ?>
</select>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi man, thx before, i appreciate your help, but this still doesn't work.. the data doesn't appear.. :(

Comment: It could probably mean that the `query` you're running doesn't generate any value. You can print the `query` by `echo $this->db->last_query();` and then run the `query` in `phpmyadmin`. See if it returns any row.

Comment: i got this message.... SELECT * FROM `tabel_harga` JOIN `tabel_vendor` ON `tabel_vendor`.`id_vendor`=`tabel_harga`.`id_vendor` JOIN `tabel_hari` ON `tabel_hari`.`id_hari`=`tabel_harga`.`id_hari` ORDER BY `id_harga` ASC

Comment: Yes, now copy the query and run it in `phpmyadmin`, if it shows no result then it means that your query is not returning any value and your now changed code is correct.

Comment: Also, if you have included `!empty` as I suggested then you can `echo 'something';` in `else` condition and if the output is 'something' that would mean your `$tabel_harga` is empty

Comment: I've tried running it on phpmyadmin, and displaying a merged table, so what does that mean? Sorry I'm very amateur btw :(

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the output?

Comment: Ok, I think if you've changed the code as I suggested then this should work. Are there any error messages?

Comment: <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <?php
            if(!empty($tabel_harga)){
                  foreach($tabel_harga as $u)      // your foreach code here
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$u['id_vendor'].'">'.$u['nama_vendor'].'</option>';
            }
            }
            ?>
          </select>


Before that, did I write it correctly as you suggested?

Comment: No no, the model one

Comment: You know what, just last thing, share the `print_r($query)` response with me.

Comment: i got message "Message: Undefined variable: query" with your code

Comment: the image that I shared with you is still using my code

Comment: if you've changed the code in the model, then `print_r($query); die;` before `return $query;` should give you a response.

Comment: That's weird, everything looks fine to me, you should get the desired output.

Comment: It looks alright to me. Ok, one last thing, then I gotta sleep - `print_r($tabel_harga)` in your view, see if it prints anything. Also, make sure that you're loading the correct view.

Comment: Ok, everything looks alright to me, your code should work(as far as my knowledge goes); I've changed the `view` code slightly but I don't think it'll make a difference but if it does, good for you, if it doesn't, I guess it's my time to say sorry.

Comment: still same doesnt work :(, but thank you very much for sharing, really appreciete, success for you..

Answer (score 0):

try this

### view

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">All</option>
      <?php
       foreach($tabel_harga as $u)
       {
        echo '<option value="'.$u->id_vendor.'">'.$u->nama_vendor.'</option>';
       }
      ?>
</select>
```

### Models

```
class M_harga extends CI_Model{
 function tampil_data(){

     $this->db-join('tabel_vendor','tabel_vendor.id_vendor=tabel_harga.id_vendor')
     $this->db-join('tabel_hari','tabel_hari.id_hari=tabel_harga.id_hari')
     $this->db->order_by('id_harga','ASC');
     $sql = $this->db->get('tabel_harga');
    
     return $sql->result(); // returns an array of objects
}
```

### controller

```
class Harga extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('M_harga');
  $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));
}

function index(){

  $data['tabel_harga'] = $this->M_harga->tampil_data();
  $this->load->view('v_harga',$data);
}
```

Comment: i have an update model and controllers, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
db->select("name, value"); 
$this->db->from('settings'); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
if ($query->num_rows()) 
{ 
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) 
  { // Your data is coming from multiple rows, so need to loop on it. 
      $siteData[$row['name']] = $row['value']; 
   } 
   } 
  return $siteData; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).